# If it's a static object is using ref as method argument better?

Tags: c#

I have an object 'connection' which holds the path/credentials to a SQL DB.

When calling methods; we usually do this:

```
Connection con = new Connection();

GetSalesData(con);


public static void (Connection con)
{
   // Run code

}
```

As I understand, we just created two instance of connection, so that means two memory allocations. Is it better to do this:

```
Connection con = new Connection();

GetSalesData(ref con);


public static void (ref Connection con)
{
   // Run code

}
```

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3040202/4541220) by Jon Skeet and also check the article he linked to. Passing by `ref` does not make sense unless you explicitly want to change the value of the passed parameter.

Comment: `public static void (connection con)` makes no sense in any language that I know of.  There is no `connection` type, only a `Connection` type.  Be accurate, Martin.

Answer (score 2):

> As I understand, we just created two instance of connection

No, we did not. Passing a variable automatically works as pass-by-reference for reference types and pass-by-value for value types. As your connection is a *class*, this means it is a reference type and only a reference will be passed to the method. You never created a second instance of your connection.

This has nothing to do with the static modifier, neither on the variable, nor on the method.

I suggest you spent a little while reading [the MSDN on this topic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/0f66670z.aspx), especially the two links called [Passing Reference-Type Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/s6938f28.aspx) and [Passing Value-Type Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/9t0za5es.aspx).

In addition, as another commenter remarked, you may want to read the excellent [Jon Skeet on parameters](http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/parameters.html).

Answer (score 2):

When you use:

```
public static void GetSalesData (Connection con)
```

you are passing a reference to the `Connection` object as a value. As such, you can access that object via `con`. You aren't creating a second copy of the `Connection` object.

Use:

```
public static void GetSalesData (ref Connection con)
```

you are now passing a reference to the memory location that in turn references the `Connection` object. This lets you change what's in that memory location, ie you can change what `con` in the code snippet:

```
Connection con = new Connection();
GetSalesData(con);
```

refers to. It is extremely unlikely that you want to do this.